# Chamando método C# no C

Tags: c#, c

Estou tentando importar uma DLL gerada via C# no C.

Estou utilizando os métodos `LoadLibrary` para carregar a DLL, porém quando uso o `GetProcAddress` o retorno é sempre `null`. Utilizei o `GetLastError` e o código de erro é 127, que significa "function not found".

Código C#:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Testando
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("5295bba9-fd9b-474d-bd6a-2f7eef51ab71")]
    public class Teste1
    {
        public int LaVai()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Código C:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary("Testando.dll");


if(hModule == NULL){
    printf("null");
}else{
    printf("not null");
}

_TestFunc = (TestFunc) GetProcAddress(hModule, TEXT("LaVai"));  

if(_TestFunc == NULL){
    printf("null");
    printf("%d",GetLastError());
}else{
    printf("not null");
}

return 0;
```

O que está faltando?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique as seguintes condições:

**1.** Propriedade `Register for COM interop` no separador `Build` do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2.** Informação de `COM Visible` e GUID único na classe `AssemblyInfo.cs` que se encontra nas `Properties` (GUID exemplificativo):

```
// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("89ff3859-a555-4dbe-8198-c9e74d2b38c1")]
```

Compile o projeto de novo e tente então aceder ao método que pretende.